# Find $ξ \in [α,β]$ s.t. f(ξ)=h(ξ), in the [α,β] interval

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f,h: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $h$ being strictly decreasing and $f$ being strictly increasing. ($f$ and $h$ are continious) Also let $φ(x)=h(f(x))+e^{-f(x)}-f^3(x)$ be decreasing. If there is an interval of [α,β] such that $f([α,β])\cap h([α,β])\neq \varnothing $, prove that there is one only one $ξ \in [α,β]$ such that $f(ξ)=h(ξ)$.

So, we will prove that there is only one $ξ \in [α,β]$ such that $f(x)=h(x) \Rightarrow f(x)-g(x)=0 \Rightarrow t(x)=0, $ with $t(x)=f(x)-g(x)$. However I have no way to prove that $t(α)t(β)<0$ or that $0 \in t([α,β])$. Can anyone help or suggest anything else? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Say $t(x)=f(x)-h(x)$. $t$ is continuous and strictly increasing since $f$ and $-h$ are continuous and strictly increasing, so finding an $a\in[\alpha,\beta]$ such that $t(a) = 0$ is enough.

Let $l\in f\left(\left[\alpha,\beta\right]\right)\cap h\left(\left[\alpha,\beta\right]\right)$. There are unique $f_l, h_l\in[\alpha, \beta]$ such that $f(f_l) = h(h_l) = l$, since the functions strictly increasing or decreasing.

If $f_l = h_l$, we are done.

Assume $f_l > h_l$ (other case is similar). $f(f_l) = h(h_l) > h(f_l)$ since $h$ is strictly decreasing, and $h(h_l) = f(f_l) > f(h_l)$ since $f$ is strictly increasing. Then $t(f_l) > 0$ and $t(h_l)<0$, so by the Intermediate Value Theorem, there is an $a\in\left[h_l, f_l\right]\subseteq[\alpha,\beta]$ such that $t(a) = 0$.